# How to read JSON in order to get the last video from YouTube

Tags: javascript, json, youtube

I'd like to extract the last video (only video), with title, description, etc.

I am using JSON Data API from [YouTube Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html) and using the [Video Upload By User Feed](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#User_Uploaded_Videos) in order to get the data.

I got from youtube a JSON (object?) about my Youtube's space and tried to read the JSON text, but its a suicide.

My code is :

```
<div id="ytContent"></div>        

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMyVideos(data) {
        var feed = data.feed;
        var entries = feed.entry || [];
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            var entry = entries[i];
            var title = entry.title.$t;
            $('#ytContent').append(title + "<br />");
        }
    }
</script>             

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/MYUSERNAME/uploads?alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showMyVideos"></script>
```

but if I try to do :

```
var p = eval("(" + data + ")");
alert(p);
```

I can't get a right parser. Why? How can I parse my JSON? I just need to understand which field I can use in order for me to get the last video from the feed. Also, hints/tips on getting the last video will also be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You don't receive a json-string, but a function call. If that doesn't return anything, "p" won't be defined. You will need to strip the function name out if you want to use the json object.

Comment: What JSON string? Your `showMyVideos(data)` function is treating the `data` parameter as an object, not as a string. What is there to parse?

Comment: @markzzz Is your intention to show the video player for only the last video and show it as YouTube player?

Comment: momo : yes :) How can you know this? haha

Comment: @momo : I see your post, but you have removed it? Why?

Comment: I thought it was answered and I misunderstood your question :) That's a rough steps, you might want to combine with info you get from @Groo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse the data, it is already parsed.

The url inside your `script` tags gets rendered into a function call, passing the data object as a parameter: `showMyVideos({ /* data object */ });`.

Your problem is that you are trying to access the `entry` field in the data you are receiving (`var entries = feed.entry || []`), but there is no such field in `data.feed`:

```
var data = {
    "version": "1.0",
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "feed": {
        "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
        "xmlns$openSearch": "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/",
        "id": {
            "$t": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/MYUSERNAME/uploads"
        },
        "updated": {
            "$t": "2011-09-06T08:05:27.303Z"
        },
        "category": [
            {
                "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
                "term": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video"
            }
        ],
        "title": {
            "$t": "Uploads by MYUSERNAME",
            "type": "text"
        },
        "logo": {
            "$t": "http://www.youtube.com/img/pic_youtubelogo_123x63.gif"
        },
        "link": [
            {
                "rel": "related",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/myusername"
            },
            {
                "rel": "alternate",
                "type": "text/html",
                "href": "http://www.youtube.com/profile_videos?user=MYUSERNAME"
            },
            {
                "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/MYUSERNAME/uploads"
            },
            {
                "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/MYUSERNAME/uploads/batch"
            },
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/MYUSERNAME/uploads?alt=json-in-script&start-index=1&max-results=25&format=5"
            }
        ],
        "author": [
            {
                "name": {
                    "$t": "MYUSERNAME"
                },
                "uri": {
                    "$t": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/myusername"
                }
            }
        ],
        "generator": {
            "$t": "YouTube data API",
            "version": "2.1",
            "uri": "http://gdata.youtube.com/"
        },
        "openSearch$totalResults": {
            "$t": 0
        },
        "openSearch$startIndex": {
            "$t": 1
        },
        "openSearch$itemsPerPage": {
            "$t": 25
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you get this code? :) If I open on chrome/firefox/ie I see only a string of chars :)

Comment: @markzzz: jsonlint.com. Enter `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/MYUSERNAME/uploads?alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showMyVideos` in your browser's address bar, and you will get the function call which gets executed (along with the data object). Then strip the function name and parentheses, and copy/paste the object to any editor which can format the js code  (like [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

When showMyVideos is called, `data` is already *parsed*. You don't need to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get JSON! You get JavaScript!
If you execute it using eval(),the data is automatically passed to your showMyVideos function. You don't have to parse anything ;) The data is already parsed, its an object, not a string.

Comment: So how can I know which object are generated? I'd like for example know the date for my videos, or description... and so on... (like entry.title.$t;)

Comment: Using the chrome developer tools or firebug for firefox, you can view objects that you have logged using "console.log(data);" in a tree. It´s easy to find it out with that.

Comment: And who parse this JSON to Javascript Ojects? It's a Youtube decision?

Comment: JSON is part of JavaScript, so it can be directly executed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question, I am assuming you want to get the last video and show it as video player.
In order to show the last video, the possible steps are:

- Include the script for the player itself

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://swfobject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
```

- Create your callback function. Basically what Google does is getting the JSON, parse it and call your callback function that you specified in `callback` parameter in your http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/MYUSERNAME/uploads?alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showMyVideos. In your callback you would want to show the video player for the last video. Something like:

```
    // function to load your video
    function loadVideo(playerUrl, autoplay) {
      swfobject.embedSWF(
          playerUrl + '&rel=1&border=0&fs=1&autoplay=' + 
          (autoplay?1:0), 'player', '290', '250', '9.0.0', false, 
          false, {allowfullscreen: 'true'});
    }

    // this is your callback function, Google call this function after parsing the JSON
    // and passing it as data
    function showMyVideos(data) {
      var feed = data.feed;
      var entries = feed.entry || [];

      if (entries.length > 0) {
        // show the video for the last entry
        loadVideo(entries[entries.length-1].media$group.media$content[0].url, false);
      }
    }
```

- Next you define somewhere where you want to put your video

  `<div id="playerContainer" style="width: 20em; height: 180px; float: left;">
  <object id="player"></object>
  </div>`
- Finally call the script that will invoke your callback. This should be the same as your code in the question

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/MYUSERNAME/uploads?alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showMyVideos"></script>
```

Comment: This is correct. The only problem is that the list on JSON is not ordered by Datetime of last video inserted. I need to order it before, than call that video?

Comment: If you one the most updated one, then you should do entries[0] in the function showMyVideos. I thought by last you want the last one in order. Also you could see http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#orderbysp for orderby parameter that you could order the feeds by

Comment: Yeah! :) `/uploads?alt=json-in-script&format=5&orderby=published&callback=showMyVideos"` works nice ;)